# ElasticSearch Returning Null Values on Min/Max Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

My mappings are as follows:

```
High >> Text
Low >> Text
Timestamp >> Timestamp
```

My Query is as follows:

```
{
   "aggs": {
       "range": {
           "date_range": {
               "field": "timestamp",
               "time_zone": "UTC",
               "ranges": [
                  { "key": "day", "from": "now-1d/d", "to" : "now/d" }, 
                  { "key": "week", "from": "now-7d/d", "to" : "now/d" }, 
                  { "key": "month", "from": "now-30d/d", "to" : "now/d" }
              ]
          },
        "aggs": {
          "low": { 
            "min": { 
              "field": "low.text"
            } 
          },
          "high": { 
            "max": { 
              "field": "high.text" 
            } 
          }
          }
        }
      }
      
   }
}
```

Essentially I'm attempting to get the high/low for the last day, high/low for the last week, and high/low for the last month. However, the response I get is a proper doc count for the ranges (each document is on a per minute timestamp) and a Null for each response.

Sample res:

```
{
  "key" : "month",
  "from" : 1.6589664E12,
  "from_as_string" : "2022-07-28T00:00:00.000Z",
  "to" : 1.6615584E12,
  "to_as_string" : "2022-08-27T00:00:00.000Z",
  "doc_count" : 31745,
  "high" : {
    "value" : null
  },
  "low" : {
    "value" : null
  }
},
```

Can someone fill me in on what I'm doing wrong? Should I change mapping to Long?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Query is fine, just changed mapping to long, and changed text to long in query. for anyone having this (user-caused) "issue" in future.